# How to order with 3 fields in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, find

I have the following problem, I have to do a sortBy to a mongo DB collection, but with 3 types of fields that are type int / number.

I currently have the query

`await Products.find({}).sort({ miShopPrice: -1, discountPrice: -1, normalPrice: -1 })`

but this returns me:

```
[
        {
          "normalPrice": 250,
          "miShopPrice": 100,
          "discountPrice": 0
        },
        {
          "normalPrice": 64990,
          "miShopPrice": 0,
          "discountPrice": 0
        },
        {
          "normalPrice": 19500,
          "miShopPrice": 0,
          "discountPrice": 0
        },
        {
          "normalPrice": 1600,
          "miShopPrice": 0,
          "discountPrice": 0
        }
]
```

the condition is as follows

```
if you have miShopPrice and normalPrice -> myShopPrice
if you have miShopPrice and discountPrice -> myShopPrice
if you have discountPrice and normalPrice -> discountPrice
if you only have normalPrice -> normalPrice
```

what the query should return would be this:

```
[
        {
          "normalPrice": 64990,
          "miShopPrice": 0,
          "discountPrice": 0
        },
        {
          "normalPrice": 19500,
          "miShopPrice": 0,
          "discountPrice": 0
        },
        {
          "normalPrice": 1600,
          "miShopPrice": 0,
          "discountPrice": 0
        },
        {
          "normalPrice": 250,
          "miShopPrice": 100,
          "discountPrice": 0
        }
]
```

could you help me I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.sort({ miShopPrice: -1, discountPrice: -1, normalPrice: -1 }` means conduct a descending sort by miShipPrice, then by discountPrice, then by normalPrice, so that output is correct for this sort.

The sort you describe is ordering by a new value derived from the three fields.  This isn't supported by the sort operator directly, but using aggregation you could add this additional value with and `$addFields` stage, order on the new value with a `$sort` stage, then remove the temporary field with a `$project` stage.

Comment: I understand what you want to get, but within the new field, what should I put there to be able to filter? The sum of the 3 prices?

Comment: use $addFields to add a sort field using the 4 conditionals you mentioned, then you can sort on that field.